# Javascript .map() issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've been learning how to work with .map() function as it used pretty often for dealing with API results,

However I have a few questions that I wasn't able to solve on my own -

```
<div className="boxer">

    {users.map((user) => (
        <div className="scoreBoxx" key={user.id} id={user.id}>
            <h2 className="CardTitle">{user.videogame.name}</h2>
        {user.opponents.map((sub) => 
            <p key={sub.id} className={sub.acronym}>
                <b>Team :</b> {sub.opponent.name}  
            </p>
        )}

</div>
```

This is printing data out for me like this -

> **Team :** ZdrastvyteTimur
> **Team :** xStiKz

What I'm trying to achieve is:

> **Team :** ZdrastvyteTimur - xStiKz

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

I apologise if this question has been asked prior, I have tried searching but wasn't able to find anything similar,

I have also tried fixing my problem by using `slice()` but haven't been able to work it out yet,

Comment: You might want to consider moving your (inconsistently indented...) React JSX to separate functions to keep your code readable.

Comment: Your posted JSX doesn't have the closing `)}` for the `users.map` callback, only the `user.oppoonents.map` callback.

Comment: Please post any code/data as text, not screenshot.

Comment: Also, "ZdrastvyteTimur" and "xStiKz" doesn't appear in the JSON you've posted.

Comment: @Dai Hey, thank you for the edit and support - I know about the closing )} tags but as it wasn't important piece of code information I didn't include everything, I'm not getting any errors as I mentioned  - Just trying to experiment and learn more about array manipulation, Also regarding the JSON data - Its a live API so it keeps changing, 'xStiKz' was just an example for explain my question, Sorry about any issues this may have caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` instead of `map`.

For example :

```
<b>Team : </b> {user.opponents.reduce((previous, current) => previous + ' - ' + current.opponent.name, '')}
```

Comment: Repetitive string concatenation using `+` is potentially expensive in JavaScript, consider using `join` instead.

Comment: @Dai Yes, if you combine it with `map`.

Comment: `user.opponents.map( o => o.opponent.name ).join( " - " )`

Comment: @Rukka that did it, I had no idea it was this simple, Many thanks for your time and effort, Really appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
<b>Team :</b> {user.opponents.map((sub) => 
              <span key={sub.id} className={sub.acronym}>
          {sub.opponent.name}  
           </span>
        
            )}
```